# Using Arrays in SQL

Tags: mysql, variables

I have this sql statement:

```
DECLARE @option_id INT;

SELECT DISTINCT product_options.option_id
INTO   @option_id
FROM   product_options,
       product_options_descriptions
WHERE  product_options.product_id = '31288'
       AND product_options_descriptions.option_name = "Color";

SELECT @option_id;
```

Which works fine. What I would like to do is is use @option_id to select multiple ids into an array. However as far as I can tell DECLARE @var only works with single values and I can't find any information on array datatypes in sql.

In outline I want to do the following

```
declare @option_id;
SELECT @option_id;
DECLARE @id_array;
SELECT into @id_array WHERE id = @option_id;
DECLARE @return_array;
FOREACH @id IN @id_array {
@return_array[] = SELECT value FROM column where id = @id
}
SELECT @return_array
```

Does anyone know where I can find tutorials ect to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use temporary table , table prefixed with #

```
CREATE TABLE #YourTable (  
  YourColumn int 
)
```

LInk : http://www.sqlteam.com/article/temporary-tables

For mysql syntax : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Comment: and then I can  run standard sql commands on it? Also would I need to drop the table afterwards or does this count as a tempory table?

Comment: Yes you can run your treatments normally, and drop your table in the end of treatment

Comment: Cheers, that is what I wanted, Big green tick for you

Comment: I'am happy to help you tracer tong Thank you

Comment: That syntax (and article) is for [tag:sql-server].  For [tag:mysql], you want `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ...`.